# Map with in a map: How to clear inner map using iterators?

Tags: c++, stl

I have an STL map inside another map which has the following structure

```
typedef set<int> nexthops;
typedef std::map<int, nexthops> innerMap;
typedef std::map<int, innerMap> mainMap;


typedef std::set<int>::const_iterator nexthop_iterator;
typedef map<int, nexthops>::const_iterator innermap_iterator;
typedef map<int, innerMap>::const_iterator outermap_iterator;
```

I'm trying to insert a value in to the inner map's set for a given outer map key. Before i do the insert, i want to check the current key of the inner map for the given outer map key.

1. If the current inner key is greater than the value that am going to insert, i want to clear the entire inner map and just add this new value as the new inner map key.
2. If the current inner key is equal to the value that am going to
   insert, i will add the entry to the inner map's set.
3. If the current inner key is less than the incoming value, then just discard the incoming value.

I was able to implement the 2nd and 3rd condition, i need some help with the first condition. i.e to clear the entire inner map corresponding to a particular key in the outer map.

Thank you.

Comment: When you mention 'inner key', which map are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant the inner map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will delete all elements from a single innerMap (or create an empty innerMap if it did not exist).

```
myMainMap[outerKey].clear();
```

Comment: @NithinChandy: Glad it worked.  If this solved your problem, please click the checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done. Thank you John!

Answer (score 2):

[`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/clear) should fit your requirement.